# How to find erlang processes lingering on old code?

Tags: erlang

Using Erlang's code change capabilities, sometimes I got false using code:soft_purge(module), meaning some other process still hangs on the old code. Is there a way to find those processes? Certainly there is a bug behind it in my case and to track it down, I need to know which process lingers on the old code.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [check_process_code/{2,3}](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#check_process_code-3) function to check this.

```
AllProcessesUsingOldModule = [Pid || 
    Pid <- processes(), 
    check_process_code(Pid, module_name)].
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. Excellent answer! Appreciated.